# How to know that the graph of a derivative of a function is concave upwards or downwards

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that if $f$ increasing in some interval then the graph of $f'$ is positive. The question how do you know if the graph o $f'$ is concave upwards or downwards. Which of the next options is $f'$?

[image: Graphs]

Comment: Look at the second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming certain conditions on $f$, if $f''(x) > 0$, then $f$ is concave up, and if $f''(x) < 0$, then it is concave down. So, since you know the derivative, this is the same as $(f'(x))' > 0$ or $(f'(x))' < 0$. That is, if $f'(x)$ is increasing, then $f(x)$ is concave up, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to make explicit that I want to know if the derivative is concave up or down, not $f$.

Comment: Then you'd look at the sign of $f'''(x)$.